# Sich damit beschäftigen vs. sich widmen

Tags: meaning, difference, idiomaticity

Laut bilingualen Deutsch-Englisch-Wörterbüchern bedeuten *sich damit beschäftigen* und *sich widmen + Dat.* fast das Gleiche. Ich bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob die folgenden Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung haben. Gibt es irgendwelche Nuancen der Bedeutung dieser beiden Sätze?

> 1. Die Forscherin beschäftigt sich mit diesem Thema.
> 2. Die Forscherin widmet sich diesem Thema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Die Forscherin beschäftigt sich mit diesem Thema.
>
> Die Forscherin widme**t** sich diesem Thema.

Diese beiden Sätze sind inhaltlich völlig gleichwertig. Der Unterschied wird deutlich, wenn man sich die anderen Bedeutungen des Verbs *widmen* anschaut.

> widmen — to be devoted to sth., to dedicate oneself

Gewichtig:

> Die Forscherin widmete ihr Leben dem Kampf gegen Krebs.

Wie schwach doch der folgende, inhaltlich völlig gleiche Satz dagegen klingt:

> Die Forscherin beschäftigte sich in ihrem ganzen Leben mit dem Kampf gegen Krebs.